# How to apply a single line of CSS to an external iframe?

Tags: javascript, css

I have to include an external hosted iframe on a client's website, and I want to change the background-color of the body element.
I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function makeitblackgoddamnit(){
    top.frames['bookings'].document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
}
</script>

<iframe src="http://www.booking.com/?
aid=123456&tmpl=searchbox&ss=&width=250&bgcolor=000000&textcolor=FFFFFF
&label=label"width="250px" style="margin-left:20px;border:none;" height="250px"
frameborder="none" scrolling="no" style="background-color:black;" name="bookings"
onload="javascript:makeitblackgoddamnit();">
</iframe>
```

but it doesn't work.
I also tried some other versions, but I don't want to load an external style sheet. I cannot use any JS libraries.
Can you help me?

Comment: Might want to work on your function names :)

Comment: JavaScript doesn't appreciate blasphemy :D

Comment: Now now, semantic function names are the most useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Allowing access (read or write) to the DOM of remote websites would allow for all sorts of nasty attacks, so [browsers don't](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Comment: The browsers should at least interpret the background-color of the iframe element... :/

Comment: @Bl3tchley — … which is completely covered by the background colour of the body element of the document loaded into the frame.

Answer (score 0):

The only way this is possible is if you can alter the CSS referenced inside the Client's website.  Otherwise, there isn't much you can do to a cross-domain iFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Iframes are subject to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), you cannot interact with them using JavaScript (or CSS, iirc) unless the current and iframe domains match.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem, but the difference is that I'm not actually setting a source for the iframe I insert the html I want using jQuery. My problem is that I don't know how to include a style sheet to the iframe.

Check the code below:

```
<button id="print1" onclick="  $('#frame1').contents().find('body').html($('#div1').html() + $('#tabs-4').html() + $('#tabs-5').html()+ $('#tabs-6').html() ); window.frames['frame1'].print();">Print full report</button>
<iframe id="frame1" style="visibility:hidden;" height=1px></iframe>
```

Comment: You can't unless you have access to the iframe content itself (the file in the iframe)

Comment: @Ennui As I've mentioned before I'm not setting a `src` property here, I'm setting the content of the iframe when the button's `onclick` event fires

Comment: Please **do not ask new questions inside an answer**. Search for an answer first, and ask a question of your own if you get stuck. (You can always reference this question in your own question if you think it is relevant.)